# SSIS - Store each column from CSV into rows in table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to create an SSIS package to load data from a CSV, the tricky part is some of the columns need to be stored as rows. I better explain it with an example below.

> From CSV file to Table in a different format as shown below

[image]

Is it possible with in SSIS or using SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

What you seek is called `unpivot`.

Please see this MSDN blog post for an example.  To drop 0 values, you can use a conditional split, and push the 0 values to a garbage output.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2014/05/22/unvipot-transformation-with-a-combination-of-single-and-multiple-destination-columns.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is 90% of what I want. However I also need the flat file columns to be inserted into table, from my above example Oct-15 which a column of flat file should go into the table. If it is going to be difficult I need to ask the sender to adhere to standard set of columns. I'll try unpivot today.